# How can I execute the code inside a <script></script> only when I'll show its container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, social-networking

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sXJa6/7/) code :

## HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showDiv">Show Agency</a>

<div id="invisibleDiv">
    <script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="1035" data-format="inline" data-related="false"></script>
</div>
```

## jQuery

```
$("#showDiv").click(function () {
    $("#invisibleDiv").show();
});
```

## CSS

```
#invisibleDiv
{
    display:none;
}
```

When I load the page, I see the scripts loaded from external source, also if the div is hidden. The scripts call with some API and generate HTML/Javascript.

Well, what I'm looking for is to force the script to be unloaded if the parent is hidden; than, when I'll show it (through the link), load the script inside the div.

How can I do it? I'll avoid AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

> - **DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/HqeD2/

```
<a href="#" id="showDiv">Show Agency</a>
<div id="invisibleDiv">
<script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="1035" data-format="inline" data-related="false"></script>
</div>

$(function() {
    $("#showDiv").click(function() {
        $.getScript("http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you just want to delay the running of arbitrary scripts that are provided by the third party?  Would something like this work?

```
<div id="invisibleDiv" style="display:none">Please wait while we load some stuff from Facebook...</div>

$("#showDiv").click(function(){
    $("#invisibleDiv").show().load("http://facebook.com/whatever/andStuff");
});
```

Has the downside that you can't pre-fetch the HTML content, but I don't see any other way.

EDIT: ok, it looks like you edited the question whle I was typing this up... so YOU control the content of invisibleDiv, but you want to delay the loading of in.js?  try this...

```
$("#showDiv").click(function(){
    $("#pleaseWaitDiv").show();
    $.getScript("http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js", function(){
        $("#pleaseWaitDiv").hide();
        $("#invisibleDiv").show();
    });
});
```

Again, you have to make the user wait while the script downloads, hence my addition of pleaseWaitDiv

More edit:
New up a script node and append it.

```
var scriptNode = $("<script></script>")
    .attr("type","IN/CompanyProfile")
    .attr("data-id","1035")
    .attr("data-format","inline")
    .attr("data-related","false");

$("#invisibleDiv").append(scriptNode);
$.getScript("http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js", function(){
    $("#pleaseWaitDiv").hide();
    $("#invisibleDiv").show();
});
```

Comment: Yes, but You can't "load" a source with attributes with this method, such as `<script type="IN/CompanyProfile" data-id="1035" data-format="inline" data-related="false"></script>`

Comment: ohhh ohhh oohhhhh.  You can create a script element and append it yourself.  Give me a second to make a third edit :p

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it to your `showDiv` click function, inline scripts are processed right away...the only other thing I can think of is to have the script be loaded via ajax which you don't want.

Comment: Yeah, I should! But its not what I'm looking for :) In fact, I have to load into the div some script from src, just not an alert :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

http://jsfiddle.net/sXJa6/6/